# Opencart not sending order confirmation emails to user or admin

Tags: opencart

for some reason im the admin is unable to receive any new order email alerts.

i have enabled to notify admin on new orders and new users. I receive the new user registration emails but not order emails..

even the customers are getting an email when a order is placed but they get the email when they register.

i replaced the order.php model buy i still dont get any emails for new orders.

im using gmail with smtp. im confused coz all the emails are working except for the new orders..

can someone please let me know what might be causing it and where i should look into?

Thanks

Comment: Anything in the error logs?

Comment: @Innervisions nope.. nothing... just only the order emails are not been received

Comment: Which opencart version you are using?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?